# Connect to Remote SQL Server using powershell or cmd

Tags: sql-server

I want to connect to Remote Sql server using powershell with username and  prompt for password and when connected i need to to run a query to retrieve data from the sql server and display as output when we run the powershell script.

i have the query ready but unable to connect to remote server with the entered username and password, any one can help me out in connecting to remote sql server using powershell or cmd.

Thank you

Comment: In what way are you unable to connect? Can you share the code you are using (with any passwords removed, obviously), as well as any errors you get?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation for [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fun of `Invoke-SqlCmd` and I prefer to use `Invoke-DbaQuery`.

First of all you need to install **DBATools**: `Install-Module -Name dbatools`.

Then you can query a remote instance [this way](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery):

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance server\instance -Query 'SELECT foo FROM bar'
```

If you want to do that in bulk for hundreds of instances and nicely save the results in an Excel file [I have a tool](https://github.com/francesco1119/QueryLauncher) for that.